# How to update whole Uint8Array value using useState in React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, uint8array

```
const [dummy, setDummy] = useState([])

//Assume pdfByte is of Uint8Array(403970)

setDummy(prevState => [...prevState, pdfByte])
```

I try to update it this way but it does not work. I want to change the whole array into the new values. Is there any way to do it? Below is how the new values(Uint8Array) look like.

[image: Here is how the Uint8Array values look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use the previous values, you can simply pass on the updated value to setDummy

```
setDummy(pdfByte)
```

Comment: The updated array won't reflect immediately after setDummy due to closure. You can log it in the functional component directly to see the update or use useEffect hook like `useEffect(() => { console.log(dummy);}, [dummy]);`